# What quality management framework is used today?

Tags: quality-assurance

Some 5 years ago I have learned about ISO 9001 (and TickIT adaptation for software industry), CMMI, Sig Sigma and about IEEE standards. Now the situation is changed. E.g. many important firms do not extend their CMMI certifications and smaller firms drop their ISO 9001 certification. What software quality assurance frameworks and methodologies are being used today?

The Agile method is pervasive and it seems to me that all is based on experience and conventions on individual teams.

Maybe there is available some report or review about the current situation. Which framework is prospective and so best to invest my time to learn it?

Comment: The one that best suites your project team's needs would be used today and may be changed if situation demands tomorrow! Its really context and opinion depended.

Answer (score 1):

CMMI. ISO, ITIL and Six-Sigma, to name the better known frameworks are still used but it depends on the company or organization.
And that leads me to suggest that you could either recommend one these or adapt and create one that meets the needs of your organization.

It might be helpful to have a discussion with other stakeholders in your organization to understand what would meet their needs; sometimes customers have to comply with specific frameworks and by your organization complying with those makes your organization be perceived in a more positive light with those customers, and it cannot hurt having that as the process for the customers who do not have a preference.